# Automatic evaluation of the last expression in Ruby when NOT using IRB

Tags: ruby, debugging, ide

I'm experimenting with ruby and following some tutorials that are great for learning. When using the IRB prompt, the last expression is always evaluated in this style:

```
"hello"
=> "hello"
```

That's awesome! Now, how can i accomplish the samething when running .rb scripts? I admit it might be a bit strange to evaluate every single line in a script, but it is awesome when learning. 
So - cannot reproduce this behaviour in other IDE's (or calling .rb scripts from a command prompt) with integrated console/terminals. I've tried Aptana, jEdit, RubyMine.

I've read alot about different constants that could be set, such as $DEBUG, $VERBOSE, and calling ruby.exe with some parameters, but i don't seem to get it right anywhere.

It would be awesome with an editor just like PowerShell_ISE, and it's power is its ease of use and simplicity to run the scripts.

Comment: Are you thinking about to put something on screen? Or to simulate the console?

Comment: Not sure I'm 100% clear on what you're asking... but everything in ruby returns a value (that's what IRB is showing). So say x = 3 + 4 is a line your .rb script you can put "puts" in front of it and it will output 7. Or x = y = 3 for example will set x and y to 3

Comment: @Kansha but using `puts` (and `warn` is better, IMO) is not the same as running a script, because you don't need to call anything for the output to go to the console in IRB, it just does it. IRB must hook in a method or wrap every call in a block somehow. The OP is just asking how to make this happen from a script. I actually think this could be very useful to do.

Comment: Oh interesting. I never really thought of that.

Comment: @iain Yes exactly, somehow IRB does this automatically. Question is how, and how do you replicate this behaviour in other circumstances? Using puts is not the same thing, because puts seem to stringify the expression, not showing the same thing as IRB does.

Answer (score 2):

1. Decide the command name to type in the terminal in order to execute the script (suppose this is `test_ruby`).
2. Decide the file name that you would always work on when you write your scratch code (suppose this is `test_ruby_file`).
3. Write a file named `test_ruby` with the following content:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env ruby

   File.open("path_to_test_ruby_file/test_ruby_file"){|io| p eval(io.read)}
   ```
4. Give `test_ruby` an executable status.
5. Write something in `test_ruby_file`.
6. In the terminal, type `test_ruby`.

Comment: Pro-tip: when using 4-space code blocks with lists, you have to add another 4-space padding :)

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev Thanks for the edit. I didn't have full handle of that. I learned something new. I actually forgot to write the shebang command in the beginning (`#!/usr/bin/env ruby` or something). Would you mind adding that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more versatile if you'd take the target script as `ARGV` and put `test_ruby`'s folder in your PATH?

Comment: @Baboon Then you would always have to pass the argument name together with the command. That is not convenient.

Comment: Nice. It does seem like it's only the last statement that gets output to the console, not all of them.

Comment: Since every line in IRB is interpreted and every statement is evaluated and output as an expression, I can understand why that behaviour cannot be reproduced line by line when running a .rb file.

So the way i'm doing it now is just using "p " before any statement that i need to see the evaluation of.
Not as helpful as the evaluation info from IRB, but it does the trick for now.

Is there any better way of doing it ?